# How deep do I need to know TSQL to fully grasp everything in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, t-sql, ssms

How deep knowledge of T-SQL do I need to have in order to fully grasp all concepts of EF (Entity Framework)?

To be more precise, currently my knowledge of SQL is not small. I know all the basics very well as well as some intermediate concepts like stored procedures, UDF, trigers etc.

But do I need to know things such as XQuery and XPath, SQL CLR Programming or Catalog Views and Dynamic Management Views to fully understand EF or this is not needed as EF has it's own way of achieving the same thing?

I hope you don't find this question stupid as it will save me some time due to my novice knowledge of EF.

I have to add that I am not a database administrator nor will I be (at least for now) but a .NET developer learning EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have to know **less** with EF than without it. It shields you partially from the underlying database technology. You kind of have to accept trade-offs the less you know (worse performance or inelegant design). But you don't need any of the things you quoted:

> But do I need to know things such as XQuery and XPath, SQL CLR
>   Programming or Catalog Views and Dynamic Management Views to fully
>   understand EF or this is not needed as EF has it's own way of
>   achieving the same thing?

Because mostly, they are not supported by EF anyway...

Comment: Thanks, I read it is good if you know foreign Key/ primary key etc. for EF but was wondering about advanced concepts. You made that clear. But why do you say it is less elegant or worse performance if you use EF? EF should be only a bridge between code (for example C#) and data (in SQL) ?

Comment: @AntunTun Because the EF query builder doesn't always make the best query plan decisions, let alone readible sql statements in certain cases. Furthermore, if you do not have a firm grasp of database concepts you are much more likely to create very inefficient code that has tons of unnecessary round trips to the db.

Comment: Well, knowing SQL Server often helps to debug stuff and fix theu nderlying problem. For example you can fix some EF shortcomings with table-valued functions or views if you have to (for example to apply locking hints). The more you know the more tricks you can apply.